# web.api Delegating handler gives 404 when executing innerhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am creating an web.api (v1 in c#) for an iOS app.
The app is sending gps-date to the app in 1 burst. So we wanted to gzip the data in the app and then process that data.

I created a DelegatingHandler

```
public class GZipToJsonHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public GZipToJsonHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
    {
        InnerHandler = innerHandler;
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            /* removed unzip code */
            /* removed log call */
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and added a custom route

```
var handler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  "WithGZip",
  "client/GPSDataWithGZip",
  null,
  null, new GZipToJsonHandler(handler)
);
```

When the app calls the route, I can see in the log-files that the handler gets called.
But when it hits `base.async` it returns "No HTTP resource found that matches the requested URI"

I've added a lot of logging, but I cannot seem to find why it cannot find the resource it has already hit

in the client controller I have this action

```
public HttpResponseMessage GPSDataWithGZip([FromBody] GpsRequest model)
{
    return SaveGPSData(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the InnerHandler couldn't match the current url to a route.
after adding default to the route it worked.

```
defaults: new {controller='client', action='GPSDataWithGZip'}
```